# git push commits from one remote to another without locally storing the files

Tags: git, github, gitlab, webhooks

I want to create a webhook server that just pushes all the commits from one remote to another.

Eg: Someone pushes to gitlab and triggers a webhook. My server recieves the hook and transfers the commits from gitlab.com/repo to github.com/repo.

Is there a way to not

```
git clone gitlab.com/repo
git remote add github/repo github
git push github
```

and just push without taking up HDD space (having the repository locally)?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it in the webhook and you don't need to clone a repository because Gitlab hosts all you repositories. You can run `git push` from your Gitlab repo to your Github repo. But of course, the user that runs the Gitlab webhook should have permissions to fetch/push with Github repos.

Comment: @ElpieKay I'm not sure you understood my question or am I not understanding you answer? Is it possible to not have any local repositories?

Comment: If you have two repositories, either can be the "local" or the "remote". You can always push from one(local) to the other(remote). Now you already have two repositories, one in Gitlab and the other in Github. So it's not necessary to clone and create another repository in your local machine or anywhere else, although it is also reasonable, just another workflow. Gitlab hosts repositories and support webhooks. So in a webhook, you can run commands to push from the Gitlab repository to another repository, which is one hosted in Github in this case.

Comment: @ElpieKay yes, but can I push from one remote to another remote without having a local repository?

Comment: Of course. "remote" and "local" are not constant. When you push from A to B, then A is the local and B is the remote. When you push from B to A, then B is the local and A is the remote. A and B can be on the same machine or on different machines, or even they can be the same repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay sorry for drawing this out but I want to push without having ANY local repos. As in just writing `git push gitlab.com/repo github.com/repo`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what your "webhook" is. So the webhook is not in the Gitlab server? If it's not, you can still do something in the webhook to tell the Gitlab server to run "git-push" from the Gitlab repository to the Github repository. What I've learned about Gitlab is that it has its own hooks which work like git hooks. When an event (receiving a push for example) happens in Gitlab, a specific hook is invoked.

Comment: @ElpieKay Sorry for not specifying, I'm talking about the Webhook in the integrations tab of a official gitlab repository. It executes a http post request on push which I try to respond to on a seperate (http) server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this isn't possible without having a local repository...

Comment: If gitlab won't let you run hooks that do that, then gitlab won't let you run hooks that do that.  Git can certainly push direct from any repo.